# Best way to handle where clause in Lambda

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda

I have the following lambda for a simple search page using MVC:

**Name and PostedName are strings.**

**Results.where(a=>a.Name.Contains(PostedName)).ToList();**

Thanks great when PostedName has a value (excellent filter), but when it is empty, I get bupkas (empty list).

I would ideally like my *where* clause to be ignored when *empty* string.

How can this be done?

Something ideally shorthand without ifs and elses and whatifs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dynamically add the `WHERE` clause.  Keep in mind that you're just building an expression tree with these clauses and it's not actually *executed* until, in this case, you call `.ToList()`.  So you can do something like this:

```
var filteredResults = Results;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(PostedName))
    filteredResults = filteredResults.Where(a => a.Contains(PostedName));
filteredResults = filteredResults.ToList();
```

Depending on the types you may need to explicitly declare a type for `filteredResults` in order for that to compile.

If you want something a little more in-line, this may do the trick:

```
Results.Where(a => string.IsNullOrWhitespace(PostedName) || a.Contains(PostedName)).ToList();
```

I think it's less clear on the intent, though.  The benefit of the first example is also that you can add more filters following the same structure, basically dynamically adding more `WHERE` clauses for other filter fields as needed.

Comment: Wow, David what a thorough mouth full! Thanks!

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsNullOrWhiteSpace(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. @David

Comment: @Pinch: That's interesting, because I really don't :)  I included it as an option, but for readability and clarifying the intent of the code I really prefer the first option.  The inline one can be made more readable if the condition is extracted into its own method, but depending on what your LINQ is evaluating against.

Comment: +1 for IsNullOrWhiteSpace which is very efficient. Unfortunately it appears in .NET >= 4.0

Comment: @Pinch: LINQ to Entities can't translate `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`?  That's... unfortunate.  Might be another reason to use the first version :)  Though I suppose you could just make the conditional in the second a little more manual, with things like `a.Equals(string.Empty)` and `a == null` and things like that, making it even less clear...

Answer (score 0):

David's answer is correct, but if you want a shortcut you can create an extension method to simplify usage  [example (untested by me)](http://www.extensionmethod.net/csharp/ienumerable-t/whereif).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
Results.Where(a => a.Name.Contains((PostedName ?? "").Trim())).ToList();
```

`"ThisIsAString".Contains("")` returns true.

In the case PostedName is null, it will be changed to "".

If there is leading and/or trailing blanks characters in PostedName, then they will be removed.